# How to serve up a GET request from Azure Function and Storage Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

For this frontend request `<img src="img/abc.png">` I have the following Azure Function (AF) to access the image file at Storage Blob

function.json

```
"methods": ["get"],
"route": "img/{filename}"
```

index.js

```
const bbc = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("pngfiles").getBlockBlobClient(context.req.params.filename);
```

After this line, I don't know how to read/fetch/stream or whatever to serve up the request from AF to frontend. I've tried the following but it returns meta data and properties

```
const png = await bbc.download();
context.res = {body: png,  headers: {"Content-Type": "image/png"}};
```

Comment: Did you try the doco?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-node-latest#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure if the best way but Works:

```
const bbc = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("pngfiles").getBlockBlobClient(context.req.params.filename).downloadToBuffer();
context.res = {body: bbc, headers: {"Content-Type": "image/png"}};
```